# ¿Cómo hago para eliminar formato hora de mi columna FECHAS?

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un *dataframe* que antes estaba en EXCEL y lo transforme  CSV. El problema es que a la hora de transformarlo a CSV, en la columna *FECHAS* aparece la hora al lado de la fecha, por ejemplo: `12/10/2022 0:00:00`.

Intenté hacer una función para eliminar los ceros pero a la hora de correrlo me tira un `KEYERROR` que dice que no existe la columna *FECHAS*, pero si existe.

No se si es cuando transforme los archivos EXCEL a CSV que la columna quedo mal. Acá el código que estoy usando para que recorra en todos los archivos csv que tengo en una carpeta llamada *csv*. ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

```
def eliminar_ceros(FECHAS):
    """
    Elimina los ceros de una cadena de FECHAS.

    Args:
        FECHAS (str): La cadena de FECHAS con ceros.

    Returns:
        str: La cadena de FECHAS sin ceros.
    """
    
    try:
        fecha_dt = pandas.datetime.strptime()(FECHAS)
    except ValueError:
        
        fecha_sin_ceros = FECHAS.replace('0', '-','')
        fecha_dt = pandas.datetime.strptime()(fecha_sin_ceros)
    
    return fecha_dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

dir_list = os.listdir('csv')
for archivo in dir_list:
    if archivo.endswith('.csv'):
        if not os.path.exists('csv'):
            os.makedirs('csv')
        df = pandas.read_csv('csv/' + archivo)
        df_copy = df.copy()
        df_copy['FECHAS'] = df_copy['FECHAS'].apply(eliminar_ceros)
        df_copy.to_csv('csv/' + archivo, index=False)
        print("Proceso completado.")
```

Comment: Hola, ¿seguro que ese csv concreto que se esta procesando en el momento del error tiene la columna FECHAS? De ser así, ¿te has asegurado de que pandas parsea adecuadamente el csv? Seria positivo que agregaras la traza completa de la excepción, supongo que el error lo causa la linea `df_copy['FECHAS'] = df_copy['FECHAS'].apply(eliminar_ceros)`, ¿es así? Te aconsejo al menos  hacer un `print(df_copy.info(verbose=True))` antes de esa linea o dentro de un `try-except` que la englobe para ver la estructura de ese dataframe concreto que lanza la excepción.

Comment: Lo solucione!!! el problema venia porque el csv la columna FECHAS tenia distinta formato de fecha y por eso me daba errores.

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionarlo ya que la columna FECHAS traia varias fechas ocn formatos distintos asi que modifique la funcion.

```
import pandas as pd
```

import os

def eliminar_ceros(fecha):
"""
Elimina la hora de una cadena de fecha.

```
Args:
    fecha (str): La cadena de fecha con hora.

Returns:
    str: La cadena de fecha sin hora.
"""
try:
    # Intenta convertir la fecha a un objeto datetime con el formato 'año-mes-día hora:minuto:segundo'
    fecha_dt = pd.to_datetime(fecha, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
except ValueError:
    try:
        # Si falla, intenta convertir la fecha con el formato 'día/mes/año'
        fecha_dt = pd.to_datetime(fecha, format='%d/%m/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        # Si todavía falla, devuelve NaN
        return pd.NaT

# Devuelve la fecha sin la hora
return fecha_dt.date()
```

dir_list = os.listdir('csv')

for archivo in dir_list:
# Si el archivo es un csv
if archivo.endswith('.csv'):
# Abre el archivo
df = pd.read_csv('csv/' + archivo)

```
    # Elimina la hora de la columna 'FECHAS'
    df['FECHAS '] = df['FECHAS '].apply(eliminar_ceros)

    # Guarda el DataFrame modificado en un archivo CSV
    df.to_csv('csv/' + archivo, index=False)

    print("Proceso completado.")
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi se me ocurría que el error se debía a que la función eliminar_ceros está intentando acceder a la columna FECHAS del DataFrame df_copy, columna que no existe ya que la función apply crea una nueva columna con el mismo nombre que la columna original, pero no la reemplaza. Modificaría la última parte así:

```
dir_list = os.listdir('csv')
for archivo in dir_list:
if archivo.endswith('.csv'):
    if not os.path.exists('csv'):
        os.makedirs('csv')
    df = pandas.read_csv('csv/' + archivo)
    df['FECHAS'] = df['FECHAS'].apply(eliminar_ceros)
    df.to_csv('csv/' + archivo, index=False)
    print("Proceso completado.")
```

Asegúrate de que la columna FECHAS de todos los archivos CSV tenga el mismo formato de fecha. Si los formatos de las fechas son diferentes, el código no funcionará correctamente.

Comment: ahh buenisimo probare gracias